# How can I implement vaadin date-picker in my Angular2 forms

Tags: angular, vaadin

I have implemented vaadin date-picker in one of my pages. I want to assign formControl to the vaadin datepicker directive but it is showing error like this

```
 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''
```

And I have built the form in this way

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm">
     <div>  
        <label for="skuInput">SKU</label>  
        <vaadin-date-picker label="Pick a date" [formControl]="sku"></vaadin-date-picker> 
     </div>
     <button (click)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

And included the datepicker directive like this

```
directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,Date,PolymerElement('vaadin-date-picker')],
```

What is the correct way to use vaadin datepicker in Angular2 forms?

Answer (score 0):

Data binding between Polymer elements (like vaadin-date-picker) don't work out of the box. You might get it work to by using [angular-polymer adapter](https://github.com/platosha/angular-polymer).